# Show banner ads within Grid Recycler View Blocks Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I am trying to implement some `banner ads` to show within my `GridRecyclerView`. Ads show and work well just that they don't show in the position I want them. I want the ads to show vertically just between the items.

These are my expected and returned output.

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4oIN.png)

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU0vO.jpg)

**This is my code**

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    AdView adView;
    final MyViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
        adView = new AdView(mContext);
        adView.setAdSize( AdSize.BANNER);

        adView.setAdUnitId(mContext.getString(R.string.following_adunit_id));

        float density = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height);
        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        //ad request
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(adView);
        return viewHolder;
    }else{
        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.neighbourhood_item,parent,false) ;
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(mData.get(position).getUser_fullname());
    holder.user_name.setText(mData.get(position).getUser_username());
    //if city or country is absent remove the location icon
    if(mData.get(position).getCity().equals("") && mData.get(position).getCountry().equals("")){
        holder.location_icon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.location.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    holder.location.setText(mData.get(position).getCity());
   // Load Image from the internet and set it into Imageview using Glide
   Glide.with(mContext).load(Constants.STORAGE_URL+
           mData.get(position).getThumbnail()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);

    Glide.with(mContext).load(Constants.STORAGE_URL+
            mData.get(position).getUser_avatar()).apply(option).into(holder.circularImageView);
    holder.mContainer.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        loadFullScreenActivity(position);
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    if ((position+1) % 5 == 0 && (position+1) != 1)
        return AD_TYPE;
    return CONTENT_TYPE;
}
```

As you can see, the ads show as a new grid item instead of between the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set item span to your recycle view to archive the result [SpanSizeLookup](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup).

```java
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch(yourAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                    case MyAdapter.AD_TYPE:
                        return 2;
                    case MyAdapter.CONTENT_TYPE:
                        return 1;
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I get this error: not static method 'getItemViewType' cannot bee referenced from a static method

Comment: getItemViewType is not a static method you need to call in on the initialized object. `YourAdapter yourAdapter = YourAdapter(); `